# Can you escape death in Final Destination?

Tags: final-destination

I've watched a couple of Final Destination movies, and I'm curious if anyone can escape death til natural old age, or is death always hunting for those who escaped? I think it's the second one, where Ali Larter saved herself by locking herself up, but eventually Death gets her too. Is there anyone who survives? Or is death in this universe the ultimate killer?

Comment: Yes, you can kill someone and take their days; http://finaldestination.wikia.com/wiki/Death's_design

Comment: Spoiler alert: we all die in the end.

Comment: @Yasskier - [Nooooooo!!!!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WWaLxFIVX1s)

Comment: @Valorum sound like an answer, as all the other methods failed and this one was only working one in some way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm surprised that noone has thought of it, but I think  that the only way to survive in the final destination universe  is to go back and look at what the undertaker character said in second movie, only new life can cheat death. Tha answer,  in my opinion,  is that someone who survives from the initial tragedy has to either get pregnant or get someone pregnant. A new life, one that wasn't meant to exist, but also wasn't 'saved'  at the last minute because its parents weren't meant to live, would  change the way things go and reset the ldeath ist.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Answers are supposed to be based on evidence provided by the movies or their creators.  Can you give any support for this from canonical sources?  Right now this just sounds like you're inventing this idea.  Please read [answer].

Comment: @DavidW I think I recognise what they’re talking about from a synopsis: it was in the car crash one, where a road pile up was the disaster. One woman/survivor there was pregnant and it was said that if the baby was born the other survivors would also get to live, because of this new life that never would have existed - although it turned out later in the movie, that the woman would have survived anyway and didn’t cheat death, so this didn’t work in this case. I do not remember the exact name/number of which Final Destination this is though.

Answer (score 8):

Per the Final Destination Wiki article on '[*Death's Design*](http://finaldestination.wikia.com/wiki/Death's_design)', it rather depends on what you consider to be "escaping death". While numerous attempts have been made in the film series to cheat death, the only one shown to be *consistently successful* is for someone marked for death to kill someone not marked for death, thus *gaining their days*.

> Three instances of this occur in Final Destination 5. **Nathan kills
>   Roy, receiving his few remaining days;** Roy having an illness that
>   would have killed him shortly anyways. Nathan thus dies shortly after,
>   but not in the original order of death planned by Death, only as the
>   time of death for Roy originally. **Peter kills Block, avoiding Death's
>   schedule.** Similarly, **Sam kills Peter, avoiding Death's schedule.** Sam
>   dies shortly after, as Block had been scheduled to die not long after
>   his actual death. There is a bit of a rift here, as Sam was not
>   technically killing someone who wasn't meant to die in the first
>   place.

Presumably if their allotted timespan was longer than your own, you would actually live *longer* than you were originally intended.

Comment: I'm intrigued by the downvote. Is there any reason you feel that this answer isn't helpful?